# Can we load the members of a SharePoint Group inside a People/Group sharepoint field

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

We have a SharePoint field which is linked to SharePoint group, as follow:-

[image]

now we added this field inside a Power Apps form >> but when the user click on the related combo-box, the user will not get the group members to select from, and the user will have to type the user email address. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a similar functionality.

1. Group the users in an M365 group
2. Load its members with the AzureAD connector into a collection.
3. Bind the collection to the dropdown in your form.
4. Use this syntax in the form card's Update property to create a 'claims' object that the Person or Group field in SharePoint will accept: `{Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|" & User().Email,Department:"",DisplayName:"",Email:"",JobTitle:"",Picture:""}`